# Delphi: Is there a tool that can remove conditional directives for particular conditional symbols?

Tags: delphi

I have many units that contain many conditional directive blocks such as:

```
{$IFDEF DELPHI6ANDLOWER}
  *Do something 1*
{$ELSE}
  *Do something 2*
{$ENDIF}
```

Now, I decide to drop the support for Delphi 6 (VER140) and the lower versions.

Is there a tool that can do the magic? Hopefully, the above code becomes:

```
  *Do something 2*
```

I have tested ModelMaker, CnPack, GExperts, but none of them could do the magic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The freeware program DIPP from Delphi Inspiration can remove conditionals.

http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/dipp/index

Comment: Here's another one:

http://clootie.narod.ru/delphi/download_utils.html#ppp

I think this is the one I actually preferred but I haven't used either in a few years so I had to dig through my bookmarks file.

Comment: @Jeroen, I think you mean ctomita, not Astaroth :-)

Comment: @ctomita For adding really useful information, it is often better to edit your answer then to add a comment.

Answer (score 4):

First, I confirm that the [DIPP](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/dipp/index) tool mentioned by **@ctomita** works perfectly for my case.

Second, I think that it might be useful to share with people how I use the tool to solve my case example.

#### Test1.pas

```
//--------------------------------------
{$IFDEF ONE}
  ShowMessage('If ONE was defined');
  WriteLn('If ONE was defined');
  {$IFDEF ONE_ONE}
    ShowMessage('If ONE_ONE was defined');
    WriteLn('If ONE_ONE was defined');
  {$ENDIF}
{$ELSE}
  ShowMessage('If ONE was not defined');
  WriteLn('If ONE was not defined');
{$ENDIF}
//--------------------------------------
{$IFNDEF ONE}
  ShowMessage('If ONE was not defined');
  WriteLn('If ONE was not defined');
{$ELSE}
  ShowMessage('If ONE was defined');
  WriteLn('If ONE was defined');
{$ENDIF}
//--------------------------------------
```

To remove the all **`ONE`** conditional block from Test1.pas and with an *assumption* that *as if* there is a conditional symbol named **`ZERO`** currently defined, use this command from the Command Prompt:

```
dipp -o -c -dZERO -h-ONE "Test1.pas" "Test1_output.pas"
```

#### Test1_output.pas

```
//--------------------------------------

  ShowMessage('If ONE was not defined');
  WriteLn('If ONE was not defined');

//--------------------------------------

  ShowMessage('If ONE was not defined');
  WriteLn('If ONE was not defined');

//--------------------------------------
```

Note that when the **`-c`** option is specified, DIPP skips over code enclosed by undefined conditionals, inserts include files depending on defined conditionals. In other words, DIPP treats source codes like the compiler would.